# NGINX running 2 node instances and a static site. Node instances need separate static folders

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a static html site, and 2 node instances running on a server. Everything is working below for site1, but I cannot figure out how to modify the /static/ location so that site2 can access its own public directory.

```
 root /home/username/;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name siteurl.com;

        location / {
          root /home/username/web/;
        }

        location /site1/ {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/site1/;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /site2/ {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/site2/;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /static/ {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000$request_uri;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$port` variable instead of hard coding the port number into the static proxy pass.